# Validar enteros positivos

Tags: c

Necesito realizar la validación de datos en c del siguiente programa. Mi duda es ¿Cómo realizo la validación para que el programa solamente acepte números enteros positivos?

El código del programa es el siguiente, pero no sé cómo hacer que el programa no acepte números negativos ni letras.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 

  int i,j,n,time,remain,flag=0,quantum; 
  int t_espera=0,t_retorno=0,at[10],bt[10],rt[10]; 
  printf("Inserte el numero de procesos:\t "); 
  scanf("%d",&n); 
  remain=n; 
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
  { 
    printf("Inserte primero el tiempo de llegada y despues inserte el tiempo de rafaga del proceso numero  %d :",i+1); 
    scanf("%d",&at[i]); 
    scanf("%d",&bt[i]); 
    rt[i]=bt[i]; 
  } 
  printf("Inserte el tiempo del Quantum:\t"); 
  scanf("%d",&quantum); 
  printf("\n\nProceso\t|Tiempo de retorno|Tiempo de espera\n\n"); 
  for(time=0,i=0;remain!=0;) 
  { 
    if(rt[i]<=quantum && rt[i]>0) 
    { 
      time+=rt[i]; 
      rt[i]=0; 
      flag=1; 
    } 
    else if(rt[i]>0) 
    { 
      rt[i]-=quantum; 
      time+=quantum; 
    } 
    if(rt[i]==0 && flag==1) 
    { 
      remain--; 
      printf("P[%d]\t|\t%d\t|\t%d\n",i+1,time-at[i],time-at[i]-bt[i]); 
      t_espera+=time-at[i]-bt[i]; 
      t_retorno+=time-at[i]; 
      flag=0; 
    } 
    if(i==n-1) 
      i=0; 
    else if(at[i+1]<=time) 
      i++; 
    else 
      i=0; 
  } 
  printf("\nEl tiempo de espera es= %f\n",t_espera*1.0/n); 
  printf("El tiempo de retorno es = %f",t_retorno*1.0/n); 

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: @Zydecic, bienvenido a SOes, sobre tu problema, pues deberias hacer un bucle con una condicion que acepte numeros mayores a 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para cualquier entero:

```
int foo;
```

Puedes hacer:

```
if(foo > 0 && !isalpha(foo))
{
//Haces lo que quieras
//Aqui ya habra filtrado si el caracter es mayor a cero y NO es alfabetico
}
```

La funcion **int isalpha(int)** esta definida en **ctype.h**

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

Otra cosa que yo cambiaria seria ese **scanf**

```
int caracter = getchar();
```

Esta linea lee un caracter desde el teclado. Esta funcion esta incluida en **stdio.h**

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

Referencias:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/

Answer (score 2):

Sacado de la documentación de `scanf`:

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

Es decir, si la función te retorna un valor igual o inferior a 0 lo más probable es que la lectura haya fallado.

Esta característica la puedes aprovechar para saber si lo que el usuario intenta introducir es un número o no:

```
int valor;
int res = scanf("%d",&valor);

if( res <= 0 )
  puts("El dato no es numerico\n");
else
  printf("Has introducido el numero %d\n",valor);
```

No hay que olvidar que, en este caso, debes limpiar el buffer de entrada para evitar lecturas sucias. Como `fflush` no es apropiado usarlo en bufferes de entrada podrías hacer algo tal que:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
```

Bien, una vez ya has verificado que el dato es numérico te queda asegurarte de que es positivo:

```
if( valor < 0 )
  puts("Por favor, introduce un numero positivo\n");
```

Otra posibilidad es leer una cadena de caracteres e interpretar los caracteres por nuestra cuenta:

```
char buffer[20];
scanf("%s",buffer);

int valor = 0;

for(char* ptr = buffer; *ptr; ++ptr)
{
  if( !isalpha(*ptr) )
  {
    puts("El dato no es numerico\n");
    valor = -1;
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    valor *= 10;
    valor += *ptr - '0';
  }
}

if( valor >= 0 )
  // No ha habido errores
```

En cuanto el dígito no sea numérico (ya sea porque introduces un caracter o el signo menos `-` el programa mostrará el mensaje de error.